# SSIS import Excel string type to float SQL Server datatype

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, trim, ssis-data-types

I have a excel file with three columns that are all empty (top to bottom) that need to be imported as float or money to a sql server table. Other excel files for those columns contain values with two decimal places. Since I can't import blank cells to a numeric column I used `LEN(TRIM(F11)) > 1 ? (DT_R8)F11 : 0` within a derived column component to write a 0 inside the db columns.

But now when I import other Excel files with values I get values like `8,4971E+20` instead of `849,71`.

Can I change the expression to take care of this or is there something else involved?

Also, instead of writing a '0' I'd like to insert NULL to the db float/money column.

Hope you can help me out with this.

**UPDATE:** let me try it another way:

I have an if expression in those empty excel columns which will just put nothing inside the cell if the value of another sheet is not a number.

If I could use the "else" statement to insert a numeric value to each cell or maybe NULL I could import directly as float. I tried putting '**0**' or '**NULL**' in the else statement but I guess because of the quotation marks around them, they will be interpreted as string.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're the same TonyC that posted [a similar question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/0d99d309-256d-4b64-bfc1-d06674c266a2).